# Example client implementation for the Service Location Protocol?

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

Does anyone know of a good example implementation of the Service Location Protocol that can be build/ran on a windows box?

Comment: What are you using SLP for?  I am curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[OpenSLP](http://www.openslp.org/) is said to compile fine on Windows.

Comment: It does, but if you want .Net support you will need a wrapper. Eg: https://github.com/inorton/slp-sharp

Answer (score 1):

OpenSLP referenced above is the code base that Novell uses for its SLP implementation for eDirectory now a days.  Not too many things really use SLP for real these days.  Usually more of a half hearted implementation