# SLP API in .net

Tags: c#, .net, api, slp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Example client implementation for the Service Location Protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130558/example-client-implementation-for-the-service-location-protocol)

Does any one know any SLP  API in .net?

Comment: By SLP, I assume you mean "Service Location Protocol"?

Comment: yup (Service Location Protocol)

Answer (score 1):

See also: slp-sharp : https://github.com/inorton/slp-sharp